# Parent component re-rendering with onClick in child component, useState resetting?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a React app that first fetches data from a search of band or song and displays it in an accordion using React Bootstrap. This looks like it works. I then want the lyrics of each song to be displayed in the card body when the header is clicked on. The fetch in the LyricsCard component onClick seems to work as I can log the data passed into the callback function getLyrics. However, the cardList state in App.js (used to render the LyricsCard components) seems to be reset to [ ], and so no accordion headers are displayed any more. Is that because App is re-rendering and any idea how I can do this separate fetch request and change the lyrics prop in the Lyrics component just when they are clicked on? I also tried placing the cardList outside of the App component, but this wouldn't render. Any help really appreciated, thanks!

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Accordion } from 'react-bootstrap';
import LyricsCard from './components/LyricsCard';
import Form from './components/Form';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
 
  const [cardList, setCardList] = useState([]);

  function getData(info) { 

    const list = info.data.map(item => (
      <LyricsCard
        id={item.id}
        key={item.id}
        artist={item.artist.name}
        title={item.title}
        lyrics="Lorem"
        getLyrics={getLyrics}
      />
    ));

    setCardList(list);
    console.log(list);
  }

  function getLyrics(id, words) {
    console.log(cardList); // gives []
    console.log(words.lyrics, id);
    const addLyrics = cardList.map(card => {
      console.log(card.id, card.lyrics);
      if (id === card.id) {
        return { ...card, lyrics: words.lyrics };
        console.log(card.id, card.lyrics);
      }

      return card;
    });

    setCardList(addLyrics);
  }

 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container bg-primary pb-5 mt-5 border border-dark rounded">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-7 mt-5 mx-auto rounded">
            <h1 className="text-center  pb-4 text-white">Lyric Search</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Form getData={getData} />

        <div className="warning-message">
          <p className="text-center">Please enter a band or song to search</p>
        </div>

        <div className="search-message my-5">
          <p className="text-center font-weight-bold">
            You searched for "Muse". Here are the first 15 results:
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className="artist-container">
          <Accordion>{cardList}</Accordion>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

LyricsCard.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Accordion, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

function LyricsCard(props) {
    const [clicked, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [alreadyClicked, setAlreadyClicked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cardID = props.id;
    console.log(clicked);
    if (clicked && !alreadyClicked) {
      fetch(`https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/${props.artist}/${props.title}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => props.getLyrics(cardID, data));
     
      setAlreadyClicked(true);     
    }
  }, [clicked]);

  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setClick(!clicked);
  }

  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Header className="bg-dark text-light text-center">
        <Accordion.Toggle
          as={Card.Header}
          variant="link"
          eventKey={props.id}
          bsPrefix="accordion-style"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          <p>
            {props.artist} - {props.title}
          </p>
        </Accordion.Toggle>
      </Card.Header>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={props.id}>
        <Card.Body>{props.lyrics}</Card.Body>
      </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default LyricsCard;
```

Form.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { InputGroup, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Form(props) {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
 
  function handleSearchChange(e) {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    console.log(search);
  }

  async function handleSearchClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.lyrics.ovh/suggest/${search}`);
    const data = await res.json();
  
    props.getData(data);
    console.log(data);    
  }

  return (
    <div className="search">
      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <FormControl
          placeholder="Enter a band or song title..."
          aria-label="Enter a band or song title"
          value={search}
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
        />
        <InputGroup.Append>
          <Button
            variant="outline-light"
            className="bg-secondary"
            onClick={handleSearchClick}
          >
            <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
          </Button>
        </InputGroup.Append>
      </InputGroup>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: as you didn't add Form component, i couldn't check fully. But it seems working here https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-benz-i4tro?file=/src/LyricsCard.js

Comment: Hi, sorry I've just added in the Form component now. The default text for the card body is Lorem at the moment, but I'll change it to an empty string when it's finished. When I click on a card header it seems to fetch the data but looks like the state is reset and so the whole accordion disappears? Thanks so much!